# Why does while loop run one time more?

Tags: javascript, loops, random

As for the question, code inside loop gets called once more after its condition becomes false. I noticed it running a debug.

```
var bPrc = (Math.random()*120.0).toFixed(4);
var aPrc = 0;
while (aPrc < bPrc){
  aPrc = (Math.random()*120.0).toFixed(4);
}
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: it does, I saw it in browser debug. Did you test it?

Comment: [I did](https://monosnap.com/file/9VBW1VyPVmMf5sTtp0FKf70kD0Qss5.png). Your test must be flawed in some way.

Comment: yes I did, and in certain cases aPrc > bPrc. I don't have evidence of this in your test

Comment: [See the second output](https://monosnap.com/file/yiCs810wkXmwbEZl0h4cpg0Uwx2KtO.png). It shows that aPrc >= bPrc. And the loop doesn't run after that.

Comment: Don't use strings

Comment: @Andreas, who is using strings?

Comment: You... [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string: "_toFixed() returns a string representation of numObj that does not use exponential notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place. The number is rounded if necessary, and the fractional part is padded with zeros if necessary so that it has the specified length._"

Comment: @Andreas: ah, good catch.

Comment: Post it as an answer, as it's right :)

Comment: Why negative votes? what's wrong with this question?

Comment: It's unclear and doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: What's unclear on it? I just noticed that every time it took a loop more, and  what should I have researched about it?

Comment: And how exactly did you "notice" it? The code doesn't produce any output.

Comment: @IginoBoffa: `while` loop most certainly doesn't run its body after condition becomes false. If you think you observed it, you should have provided a [mcve]. In this case, the example is not verifiable. Should have included debug logging or something.

Comment: @melpomene Google Chrome developing tool

Comment: Anyway, got the answer I needed. @Andreas please post it as an answer, so I can reward you

Comment: I've voted to close the question so I won't add an answer. Feel free to add an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It does not run more than defined, but exactly according to the condition. Unless your CPU is faulty... But then it would be a miracle that your OS has started up.

What happens is that you do not know what to expect from that code.
And that's understandable, given that the result is actually **random**. You are comparing **random** numbers as your stop condition.

And as to "I noticed it running a debug." - yeah, I know. You've probably evaluated `(Math.random()*120.0).toFixed(4) < bPrc` and it resulted to `false` and wondered why `aPrc < bPrc` still goes ahead.

Comment: It wasn't it... It was that toFixed output is actually a string.

Comment: It certainly WAS it, as you stated that "code inside loop gets called once more after its condition becomes false", and no matter what you say was your problem, me stating that your statement is wrong - is the correct answer. Your question is actually the wrong question, and should not be on StackOverflow.